# Chrome extension - inline installation not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension and I want to have the [inline installation](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/inline_installation.html) on my website. 
I have the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
   <head>
        <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/-extension_ID-">
        <script>
            function ExtInstall() {
                if (chrome.app.isInstalled) 
                    alert("already installed!");
                else 
                    chrome.webstore.install();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="ExtInstall()" id="install-button">Add to Chrome</button>
    </body>
```

I have also linked the website with the extension, but it does still not working. The  chrome.app.isInstalled returns always false even if I have the extension installed and chrome.webstore.install(); does nothing. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure you have put the app's URLs in the app's [manifest.json](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide.html#manifest)?

Comment: Are you sure your site is verified ('Verified site requirement' section in docs you provided)? Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: yes, in the permissions part...

Comment: chrome.webstore.install supports a failure callback parameter, which has an error string that should tell you why the installation failed. Try using `chrome.webstore.install(undefined, undefined, function(err) {console.log('inline install failed: ' + err)})`

Comment: it says "inline install failed: Installs can only be initiated by the Chrome Web Store item's verified site"
but the site is verified..
the webstore says "this item is created by the owner of the listed website" with a tick next to the website...

Comment: Can you include the extension ID and site you're trying to install from (feel free to contact me directly at mihaip@chromium.org if you don't want to share that publicly)?

Comment: I emailed you the id. Thank you!

Comment: btw, AFAIK chrome.app.isInstalled is for Chrome apps not extensions

Comment: @MihaiParparita: can you please share the update how you fixed it? Cause in 2015 i have same problem my chrome web store app is always calling failcallback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing with the poster, it turns out to be a Chrome bug, where verified sites that have port numbers are not handled correctly (i.e. if the verified site is `example.com:1337`, inline installation requests from `http://example.com:1337/install.html` will fail with "Installs can only be initiated by the Chrome Web Store item's verified site".

I have filed [Chromium bug 110917](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110917) to track this.

Comment: Can you please check if its fixed or not in Chrome Stable and Canary (year 2015) because i have the same failure problem.

Comment: The bug that I reported was fixed in 2012. I no longer work on Chrome, so I'm not aware of any new similar bugs cropping up.